# How to get full source code with JavaScript including all comments?

Tags: javascript

How to get the full source code (including comments) with JavaScript but without traversing the DOM tree of the following page?

I am looking for something like `document.innerHTML` because `document.documentElement.outerHTML` does not include the surrounding comments.

```
<!-- begin: desktop.html.tpl -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FooBar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is FooBar</p>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- end: desktop.html.tpl -->
<!-- generation time: 32.446ms -->
```

The expected result should be **exactly** this source.

Comment: Do an AJAX get request to the page?

Comment: People rating down without any comment?!

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I dont understand your question

Comment: I am looking for something like `document.innerHTML` cause `document.documentElement.outerHTML`does not return the expected result

Comment: I updated the question to make it more precise (hopefully). And if you downvoting people would please just leave a comment, WHY you downvoted, it will help me improving the question. Thank you!

Comment: I think it returns the expected result, but maybe not the desired result. :) So I assume your problem is the comments outside the html elements.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use
`$("html").html()`
In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.[Detail](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

### or

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7reffktf/)